# Data with custom date dimple.js

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, visualization, dimple.js

Currently i have this:

```
<div id="chartContainer">
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 590, 400);
    var data = [
        {'Date': '01-03-2013', 'Views': '13'},
        {'Date': '05-03-2013', 'Views': '123'},
        {'Date': '09-03-2013', 'Views': '234'},
        {'Date': '13-03-2013', 'Views': '95'},
    ];
    /*
    var data = [
        {'Date': '01-03-2013 - 02-03-2013', 'Views': '13'},
        {'Date': '05-03-2013 - 06-03-2013', 'Views': '123'},
        {'Date': '09-03-2013 - 10-03-2013', 'Views': '234'},
        {'Date': '13-03-2013 - 14-03-2013', 'Views': '95'},
    ]; */
    var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
    myChart.setBounds(70, 30, 490, 310)
    var x = myChart.addTimeAxis("x", "Date", "%d-%m-%Y", "%d-%m");
    x.showGridlines = true;
    x.addOrderRule("Date");
    var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Views");
    y.tickFormat = "d";
    var s = myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.line);
    s.lineWeight = 4;
    s.lineMarkers = true;
    myChart.draw();
    </script>
</div>
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cx8aW/)**

What should i do to get dimple.js/d3.js to work properly with commented data with range date?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specifically a dimple question, dimple just uses the d3 time format which is in turn the python format.  I'm not sure how to pad for an unknown character.  One way would be to trim the strings beforehand with some simple JS.  If you needed to keep the data as it is you could cheat by allocating the second date to milliseconds:

"%d-%m-%Y - %L-%L-%L%L"

That would basically add 13 milliseconds to each date, which would be immaterial in the display, but isn't a really great solution.